# How to set up git/git pull on Google Cloud VM

Tags: git, github, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine

I'm attempting to `git pull` from my Google Cloud VM but I'm getting a bit overwhelmed and confused with the procedure.

I was able to `git push` from my local repo to GitHub by setting up a private SSH key and linking it to my GitHub account with the public key. Would this be the exact same procedure that needs to be done on my Google Cloud VM SSH?

edit: will try and clarify better.

The GitHub repo I would be pulling from is private. However, I didn't think the process was any different between a public and private repo. When setting up my local repo to `git push` to GitHub I had to set up a private SSH key on my local PC and provided GitHub with my public SSH key. I had no problems setting this up and getting it to work.

I'm current not getting any errors as I have yet to attempt to `git pull` yet from my VM as I wasn't entirely sure how to do it. If I wanted to `git pull` from my Google Cloud VM do I simply set it up exactly as I did on my local PC - create a SSH private key on my VM and provide GitHub with a second public SSH key (1 public key for my local repo and 1 for my VM repo)?

Comment: Edit your question with details: 1) Is the repo public or private? 2) If private what authorization did you set up? 3) What command are you using to pull the repo? 4) What error are you getting? Your question needs context and details to help you. GitHub/Microsoft has free courses/labs that are excellent for learning the basics: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/paths/intro-to-vc-git/ and https://lab.github.com/

Comment: edited my question for clarification

Comment: You can use one or several SSH keys. I use one key for my development system and a different key for each deployed service.

Comment: So in this case the development system is Github? I had thought all public SSH keys were associated with a specific private key

Comment: The development system is the computer you are developing on. GitHub is a service, however, you can use GitHub to build containers as well which I use for CI/CD.

Comment: Let me rephrase here. I'm doing a bad job trying to describe what I'm trying to figure out. My goal is to get my local project to my VM by pushing to Github from my local PC (this part done) then cloning and pulling it from my VM. What is hanging me up is executing that on my VM. Do I log onto my VM and create SSH keys EXACTLY how I did it on my local computer? In the case, will Github require a second SSH key? 1 for my local PC and another for my VM?

Comment: You can use the same key or use different SSH keys that you imported into GitHub. I recommend that you follow a getting start tutorial or take one of the learning lessons in my early comment. This stuff is very simple once you understand the basics.

Comment: Will do. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Related to how to create SSH keys in a GCE environment, you can do it on a Linux  based with  the `ssh-keygen utility` to create a new SSH key pair.
As an example on a terminal you can use:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/KEY_FILENAME -C USER -b 2048
```

Replace:

```
KEY_FILENAME:  The name for your SSH key file
USER: your username
```

`ssh-keygen` saves your private key file to `~/.ssh/KEY_FILENAME` and your public key file to `~/.ssh/KEY_FILENAME.pub`.

Then you can export to GitHub. Also, if you want to know more about how GP Compute Engine store SSH keys and how manage SSH connections, you can consult this [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/ssh#third-party-tools)